# cSplit function - keep blank values while splitting

Tags: r

I want to split concatenated values of a column B into separate rows based on other column A. The result will have as many rows as the concatenated values in B for which value of A will be duplicated.

But, there can be blank values also in B (column to be split).
I just want those records to be retained not to lose those values of A. Below is my data frame.

```
s<- data.frame(A=c(1:3,4:6),B=c("a,b","b,c","b",rep("",2),"a,b,cd,e"))
s
A     B
1   a,b
2   b,c
3   b
4   
5   
6   a,b,cd,e
```

You can see blank values in B for 4 & 5 in A. When I use `cSplit` function, those records are getting removed.

```
sp<-cSplit(s,"B",",",direction = "long")
sp
A  B
1  a
1  b
2  b
2  c
3  b
6  a
6  b
6 cd
6  e
```

But I need the result to be like this. Include those rows with blank values in B

```
sp
A  B
1  a
1  b
2  b
2  c
3  b
4
5
6  a
6  b
6 cd
6  e
```

Is there any options in `cSplit` to retain the blank values or any other way of acheiving this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you consider adding a feature request on the GitHub issues page and I'll see if anything can be modified to make it work as demonstrated in my answer below? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no setting to change that, but you can work around it by first splitting into a `list` and then using `listCol_l` to get `NA` values where blanks were:

```
library(splitstackshape)
listCol_l(cSplit_l(s, "B", ",", drop = TRUE), "B_list")
##     A B_list_ul
##  1: 1         a
##  2: 1         b
##  3: 2         b
##  4: 2         c
##  5: 3         b
##  6: 4        NA
##  7: 5        NA
##  8: 6         a
##  9: 6         b
## 10: 6        cd
## 11: 6         e
```

You may need to add a `[]` at the end of the line if the output is not printing, in other words:

```
listCol_l(cSplit_l(s, "B", ",", drop = TRUE), "B_list")[]
```

Comment: I don't think it prints for v 1.9.5, probably will need to fix that too

Comment: @DavidArenburg, probably a missing `[]` somewhere after having used `:=`.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure if this optimal to put that into the source code for cases when someone wants to save the result instead of just printing it (which is always in real life). I think you can leave it as is and add `[]` only on SO answers when you just printing the result.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, isn't that the recommended approach? I thought I recalled seeing that in the readme somewhere.... Anyway, I'll have to look into it.

Comment: There is no need to print results when assigning to a new object I guess